# A conductive ball connected to a capacitor

Tags: capacitor, charge, electrostatic

I am not asking for a task solution, but rather how to solve a problem. 
Say I have a ball of radius R, charged to a voltage of U (relative to the ground). 
I also have a flat capacitor with a side area of S, and distance between the plates of d.
Then, I connect one side of the capacitor to the ground, and the other side, with a non-capacitive wire, to the ball. 
What will be the potential of the ball and the charge flowing from the ball to the side of the capacitor?

My approach would be:
1. Calculate the capacitance of the ball and the capacitor, given the capacitance, calculate the ball's charge 
2. Calculate the total capacitance of the connected ball and capacitor while assuming the charge doesn't change and they are connected in parallel 
3. Given the total capacitance and the constant charge, calculate the voltage (or potential) which will be the same both for the ball and the capacitor, since they connected in parallel. 
4. Using the voltage and the capacitance of the ball, calculate the new charge of the ball
5. Difference of the starting charge and the new charge is the amount of charge flowing through the wire

Is my approach correct?
Also, is the ball really connected in parallel to the capacitor? Logical reasoning would imply they are connected in series, but I can only find a solution to this problem if I assume they are connected in parallel (I must admit it is a blind try). Can someone justify if, and if yes, why are they connected in parallel?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! A picture or sketch is worth a thousand words here.

Comment: @laptop2d i have removed the duplicate on the physics site

Comment: Are you talking about the capacitance between a sphere and plate?